# how to extract complete text in paragraph tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to extract complete text except `<p><a href><rel>` etc from the following html code.

```
<p>Many of the features that made the Samsung Galaxy S4 one of the most anticipated phones in recent history -- such as its 5-inch 1920 x 1080 <a href="http://www.bubblews.com/news/421662-samsung-galaxy-s4-worlds-first-full-hd-super-amoled-display" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Full HD Super AMOLED display</a>, its powerful processors (<a href="http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/Exynos/blog_Spotlight_on_the_Exynos5Octa.html" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Samsung Exynos 5 Octa</a> in the international version and <a href="http://www.qualcomm.com/snapdragon/blog/topics/snapdragon 600" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Qualcomm Snapdragon 600</a> in the U.S. version) and 16GB, 32GB and 64GB storage options -- are now bringing grief to those who rushed to purchase the fourth-generation Galaxy S series smartphone upon its late April release.</p>
```

i have tried the below code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

BASE_URL = "http://www.chicagoreader.com"

def get_category_links(section_url):
    html = urlopen(section_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    for div in soup.findall("div", attrs={'class':'field-content'}):
          print div.find("p").content[0]
```

But is giving the following output

Many of the features that made the Samsung Galaxy S4 one of the most anticipated phones in recent history -- such as its 5-inch 1920 x 1080

i am unable to get the complete text, it should give the text after the href and rel etc tags, please suggest me how to get the below output.

Many of the features that made the Samsung Galaxy S4 one of the most anticipated phones in recent history -- such as its 5-inch 1920 x 1080 Full HD Super AMOLED display its powerful processors .Samsung Exynos 5 Octa in the international version and ">Qualcomm Snapdragon 600 in the U.S. version) and 16GB, 32GB and 64GB storage options -- are now bringing grief to those who rushed to purchase the fourth-generation Galaxy S series smartphone upon its late April release.

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.text`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '<p>Many of the features that made the Samsung Galaxy S4 one of the most anticipated phones in recent history -- such as its 5-inch 1920 x 1080 <a href="http://www.bubblews.com/news/421662-samsung-galaxy-s4-worlds-first-full-hd-super-amoled-display" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Full HD Super AMOLED display</a>, its powerful processors (<a href="http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/Exynos/blog_Spotlight_on_the_Exynos5Octa.html" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Samsung Exynos 5 Octa</a> in the international version and <a href="http://www.qualcomm.com/snapdragon/blog/topics/snapdragon 600" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Qualcomm Snapdragon 600</a> in the U.S. version) and 16GB, 32GB and 64GB storage options -- are now bringing grief to those who rushed to purchase the fourth-generation Galaxy S series smartphone upon its late April release.</p>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print soup.p.text
Many of the features that made the Samsung Galaxy S4 one of the most anticipated phones in recent history -- such as its 5-inch 1920 x 1080 Full HD Super AMOLED display, its powerful processors (Samsung Exynos 5 Octa in the international version and Qualcomm Snapdragon 600 in the U.S. version) and 16GB, 32GB and 64GB storage options -- are now bringing grief to those who rushed to purchase the fourth-generation Galaxy S series smartphone upon its late April release.
```

Comment: thanks, its working, but i need to extract complete text from a website,i should not do hard code the value in html variable as you mention in above code it should take from url as i mention in my code please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: @vittalcherala I'm sorry, I would but I can't seem to get your code to work. Maybe the website has changed?